# Slideshow in android

Tags: android

I am seeking some pointers on how to create a sideshow application in Android.  I need to have the Android transition animation when I switch between the images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fade the images in and out (or probably use other transitions) using the Animation classes in Android. Here is something which I use

```
Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
animation.setDuration(100);
animation.setRepeatCount(0);
animation.setFillAfter(true); 
myView.startAnimation(animation)
```

Then load the other image when this completes. You can use an [AnimationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html) to detect the animation end.

After the animation do the same thing but reverse the alpha values in AlphaAnimation.